# Overcome API limits with Python threads

Tags: python, multithreading, api, google-colaboratory

I am trying to get data from AppCast API. Unfortunately, it has limits, max 100 jobs per page and when I try to iterate over the pages, it only queries 50 pages. To overcome this, I generate URLs based on ZIP Code, Discipline_ID (it's like a category of the job), and Page, final URL looks like this:
`https://api.appcast.io/search?page={page}&discipline_id={discipline_id}&l={zip}&jobs_per_page=100`

Here is the code I use now, I am trying to run it on Google Colab, but it runs out of RAM very soon.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json
import uuid
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed

headers = {
    'x-api-key': ''
}

discipline_ids = [0, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21,
                  22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 
                  38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46]
zip_codes = pd.read_excel('zip_codes.xlsx')['ZIP'].to_list()
pages = [i for i in range(20)]

url_list = []
for page in pages:
  for discipline_id in discipline_ids:
    for zip in zip_codes:
      url_list.append(f"https://api.appcast.io/search?page={page}&discipline_id={discipline_id}&l={zip}&jobs_per_page=100")

counter = 0

def get_jobs(url):
  global counter
  r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
  r_length = len(r.json()['jobs'])
  if r.status_code == 200 and r_length > 0:
    with open(f'{uuid.uuid1()}.txt', 'w') as outfile:
      json.dump(r.json(), outfile)
    counter += r_length
    print(f"Number of jobs:{counter}")

def runner():
  threads = []
  with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = 20) as executor:
    for url in url_list:
      threads.append(executor.submit(get_jobs, url))

    for task in as_completed(threads):
      print(task.result())

runner()
```

What can I do to not face the RAM problem?

Ideally, I would like to get these results in one JSON file, but when I tried to do that, it would rewrite the old file with new data, I didn't find a workaround for that.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your main question is but

> but when I tried to do that, it would rewrite the old file with new data

change 
`with open('filename.txt', 'w')`
to 
`with open('filename.txt', 'a')`

The `a` option is for appending rather than `w`, writing (over/from the start)

Also you'll be able to use just one file if using append, since... well it appends to the same file

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it solved the appending part, but my main question is how to overcome the RAM problem. I have lots of URLs and threading overloads the Colab RAM.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by following this tutorial: https://developer.ibm.com/articles/au-threadingpython/

I've added this part to the script:

```
import queue
import threading

queue = queue.Queue()

class ThreadUrl(threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self, queue):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.queue = queue

  def run(self):
    while True:
      #grabs host from queue
      url = self.queue.get()

      # query an API
      get_jobs(url)

      # signals to queue job is done
      self.queue.task_done()

def main():
  # spawn a pool of threads, and pass them queue instance 
  for i in range(20):
    t = ThreadUrl(queue)
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()

  # populate queue with data   
    for url in url_list:
      queue.put(url)

  # wait on the queue until everything has been processed     
  queue.join()

main()
```